# sproutcore or cappucino for web app development?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, cappuccino, sproutcore, objective-j

I recently found out about the sproutcore and capuccino frameworks for web app development as proper MVC approach to creating Desktop-like applications.

As far as I could understand, the main difference between the two frameworks is that Cappucino abstracts away the HTML+CSS+Javascript to Objective-J - a new programming language developed be the creators of Capuccino that adds OO capabilities to Javascript, whereas Sproutcore uses HTML5,CSS,Javascript.

After lots of pondering, I thought it's probably best to go with technologies we know, so I downloaded the Sproutcore tools and did the tutorials, and I have to say I was very impressed. Just the kind of thing I was looking for, for organizing a complex web app.

However, I just stumbled across the following link:
http://charlesjolley.sys-con.com/node/1341228

in which Charles Jolley (the creator of Sproutcore) syas that he's tired of waiting for the HTML5 and ECMAScript5 specs to get finalized, and announces that from version 1.1 onwards they will be switching to Objective-J !

So now the question is - what will actually differentiate Sproutcore and Capuccino - and which one should I choose now?

Kind Regards

Swami

Comment: If you have questions about SC, I hope you visit the IRC chat room at #sproutcore or check out the mailing list at sproutcore@googlegroups.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the date of that post by Jolley. I believe it's April 1st :)

Also, I would suggest to give it a bit time, since both frameworks are terribly documented. I  tried Sproutcore because i kinda hate all that Objective-J abstraction over an awesome language like JavaScript, but I realized that Sproutcore as well has a very steep learning curve (mainly because of the lack of examples and tutorials). It also hit 1.0 a month (or so) ago and many of the examples you'll find are outdated.  I hope that in the next months the focus will be on documenting the framework.

Comment: Unfortunately it's taken a bit longer than a month to get documentation improved. However, there is currently there is beginning to be a big push towards improving documentation. 1.4 (yes 1.1 - 1.3 were skipped, long story) will be out soon and 1.5 is also under heavy development.